# Nuxt - Bulma variable overrides not taking effect

Tags: webpack, sass, nuxt.js, bulma, buefy

I'm struggling to override some but not all Bulma (via Buefy) Sass variables in Nuxt.

My overrides file is being loaded, because I can see some styles being overridden e.g. background colour. But I cannot override any of the others.

```
$button-background-color: pink; //<-- only one that works
$button-text-color: white;
$button-text-decoration: underline;
$button-text-hover-background-color: red;
$button-text-hover-color: white;
```

The button I'm testing on:

```
<b-button>Test button</b-button>
```

If I inspect the DOM, I can see the styles are being loaded from the Bulma defaults and my overrides never show up in any of the loaded CSS, so it doesn't seem to be a precedence issue.

Here's how I'm loading Bulma/Buefy and my overrides.

nuxt.config.js

```
css: [
    '~/assets/css/buefy-init.scss'
],
```

buefy-init.scss

```
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/derived-variables";
@import "~/assets/css/project-vars.scss";
@import "~bulma/bulma";
@import "~buefy/src/scss/buefy";
```

project-vars.scss

```
$button-background-color: pink; //<-- only one that works
$button-text-color: white;
$button-text-decoration: underline;
$button-text-hover-background-color: red;
$button-text-hover-color: white;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Same problem. I guess you're using styleResources to load bulma-uitilities? This is where things go wrong for me.

Comment: Correct. It's a bit of a mystery why some vars can be overridden and some don't seem to be. Might be one for the Bulma GH discussion. Do let us know if you solve it.